# Link inside fixed-width div that doesn't wrap to the next line

Tags: css, width, word-wrap

[Skip to live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/GXMRW/)

So basically I have a `<div>` that has a fixed width, lets say `200px`. It contains links, which vary on width depending on their contents...

When a link's text is long, it wraps to the next line; however, I would like the link to never wrap, but cause the parent to have scroll bars:

```
//Bad

This would be a|
long link that |
wraps, which is|
bad.           |

//Good:

This would be a| long link that doesnt wrap, which is awesome.
 <-----------> | //Scroll bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this CSS to your class: `white-space: nowrap` see more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Comment: That along with `overflow:auto` in the div worked. +1 & accepted, thanks.